# Getting escaped outerHTML into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the `outerHTML` of a div#content, with the tags escaped by `.text()`, into a variable, something like this:

```
var divContent = $('div#content')[0].text();
```

But that blows up with a Type Error: `TypeError: $(...)[0].outerHTML.text is not a function`

Can someone suggest the best way to do  this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confusing terms here. [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) it's a jquery method that gets the combined text contents of each element the selector matches.

[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants.

So:

```
var divContent = $('div#content')[0].outerHTML
```

or

```
var divContent = $('div#content').text();
```

To "escape" the text, you can use [`escape` and `unscape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions%28Obsoleted_above_JavaScript_1.5%29), or better yet, [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) like this:

```
var escaped = escape(divContent);
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(divContent);
```

Comment: Hmmm. What I want to end up with is a .html file on a disk that holds the html that was in div#content.  So the plan was that once I got the outerHTML into the variable divContent I would pass it up to the server with an ajax

 $('#statusDiv').load('savePage.php', {content :  divConent}); 

and savePage.php would write the $divContent variable into the disk file. The final .html disk  file has to have all the tags so it can be accessed by a browser and rendered. Perhaps I'm not going about this the right way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so `$('div#content')[0].outerHTML` its the way to go if you want your div to appear in the HTML, and `$('div#content').html()` if you *only* want the html content inside the div. Lastly, you might want to check [jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)